# MySQL GROUP BY without crossovers from another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table `my_table`, with fields `group_id`, `region`, `value`. I want to select the chains of values from each group, but only if `region = US` for all records in the group.

The query I initially tried is

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
             value
             ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '<-'
) AS value_chain
FROM my_table
WHERE region = 'US'
GROUP BY (group_id)
```

This is incorrect, as if there is a `US` record and a `CA` record in the same chain, the `CA` record will be omitted before the `GROUP BY`, and the `US` record will be returned as a group of size 1. In this case I don't want to return the chain at all.

Is there a good way of achieving this?
For performance reasons I would rather not build all chains from all regions and then filter if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '<-') AS value_chain
FROM my_table
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING SUM(region <> 'US') = 0
```

This will filter out groups having at least one non-'US' value.

### Visual

```
-- drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table
(   group_id int not null, 
    region varchar(20) not null, 
    value int not null,
    date date not null
);
-- truncate table my_table;
insert my_table values
(1,'US',100,'2016-01-07'),
(1,'CAD',200,'2016-01-06'),
(2,'US',700,'2016-02-07'),
(3,'CAD',666666,'2016-01-07'),
(4,'US',1200,'2016-02-04'),
(4,'US',1400,'2016-02-03');


SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY DATE DESC SEPARATOR '<-') AS value_chain 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING SUM(region <> 'US') = 0 
+-------------+
| value_chain |
+-------------+
| 700         |
| 1200<-1400  |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Out of interest, I tried this with `COUNT` instead of `SUM` first, and got no rows returned. Do you know why? I couldn't really see what would cause that from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

Comment: @rbennett485 You cannot use `COUNT` with a predicate, as `COUNT` will count *all* not null values, so it will essentially count everything.

Comment: You're the best Giorgos, +1